# I cannot use the Format function in Apophysis 7x

Tags: pascal

I am playing with a drawing software called Apophysis 7x 15D 32dit and I am having trouble writing code from Script and it throws an error. The error text pointed me to the wrong type of Format function, but I am not sure.
Here is the site I am referring to.
http://soar13065.blog55.fc2.com/blog-entry-9.html

---

- Problem/error being encountered

```
RUNTIME ERROR
Illegal argument to Format function when evaluating instruction CallProc ($1,$2,$6DDB54,$66E0E98, "Format").
Stack content is: []. Source position: 25,63.
```

---

- Corresponding source code

The code shown here is taken directly from a reference site.
The fPath and fName have been changed.

```
{ Filename : 110421.aposcript }
with Flame do
begin
    SampleDensity := 100;
    Oversample := 1;
    FilterRadius := 0.7;
end;

with Renderer do
begin
    Width := 640;
    Height := 320;
end;

Pcts := 36; //出力する枚数
fPath := 'C:\Apophysis\110421\'; //出力する画像ファイルを入れるフォルダ。事前に作っておく
fName := '110421'; //ファイル名のヘッダ文字列
fType := 'bmp'; //拡張子

for i := 0 to Pcts - 1 do
begin
    SetActiveTransform(0);
    Rotate(360 / Pcts);

    Renderer.Filename := fPath + fName + Format('_%.3d', [i]) + '.' + fType;
    SetRenderBounds;
    Render
end;

UpdateFlame := False;
```

The type of the Format function? I changed the %d to %u and still could not use it.
I referred to this site for the Format function.
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=Format

I know this software is a bit old, but if you know or have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Apophysis is internally using Pascal Scripter developed by TMS Software.  I don't have direct experience working with this pascal script engine but I do know that not all pascal scripts supports exactly the same pascal syntax that if found in other pascal languages like Delphi or FreePascal. So it seems that one of the parameters passed to Format function is not in format that script engine expects. Perhaps script engine doesn't support strings starting with an underscore character.  Perhaps making a change that code might help. ...

Comment: ... For instance in Delphi you could get the desired Filename entirely using Format function without the need of string concatenation by passing multiple parameters to Format function like this `Renderer.Filename := Format('%s%s_%.3d.%s', [fPath,fName,i,fType])`. If the pascal scripter has limitation of strings starting with underscore character this might help you avoid such limitation.

Comment: If the code change that I provided causes same error but at Source position: 25,66 then it is possible that pascal script Format function might not be able to work directly with loop control variable I. So try declaring standalone Integer variable and passing that variable to the Format function to see if error persists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried the following code as you pointed out, but it threw the same error.
`
    Renderer.Filename := Format('%s%s_%.3d.%s', [fPath,fName,j,fType]);
`
 `    j := i;
    Renderer.Filename := fPath + fName + Format('_%3d', [j]) + '. + fType;`

Comment: It appears TMS pascal script doesn't support  constructing of array parameter on the fly when passing it to function using square brackets like normal pascal does. So try this code instead `Renderer.Filename := Format('%s%s_%.3d.%s', VarArrayOf([fPath,fName,i,fType])).`  If I understand TMS scripter documentation `VarArrayOf` method should return array of multiple values that can be passed as argument to a function that expects an array as one of its parameters like Format function expects as its second parameter.

Comment: PS: You can learn more about TMS scripter and its scripting language by reading [TMS Scripter Manual](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/view/8277744/tms-scripter-manual-tms-software)

Comment: I removed some of the tags because this isn't actually Delphi

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried the code you provided and got the following error.  

`Unknown method or routine; VarArrayOf`  

Perhaps VarArrayOf is not available.  

Thank you for the TMS Scripter manual. I will read it.